# Password required for ubuntu core on raspberry Pi3 after configuration (ssh login)

Tags: server, login, password, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I followed the instructions for generating a pair of private and public key as in help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys. I uploaded the pub key on my SSO account, I copied ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img file on a sd and configured ubuntu core on my raspberry pi 3. I try to connect from another computer on my home network having ubuntu 16.04 LTS. A password is required! What password!? What is going bad?

Answer (score 0):

Your ssh keys have to be present, in the proper location, on the computer you are using to remotely login to the Pi and/or installed in the application you are using to login. If this is not the case you'll be asked for a password -- which does not exist.